# Stubbing a function in sinon to return different value every time it is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a function as shown below:

```
function test(parms) {
        var self = this;
        return this.test2(parms)
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                return ;
            }
            else {
                return Bluebird.delay(1000)
                .then(self.test.bind(self, parms));
            }
        }.bind(self));
    };
```

I am trying to write unit tests for this function. I am using `sinon.stub` to mock the functionality of the function `test2`.

I wrote a test case where `test2` returns `true` and therefore the `test` function successfully completes execution. However I want a test case where on the first instance `test2` returns `false`, it waits for delay and next time `test2` returns `true`. For that I wrote my test case as below:

```
var clock;
var result;
var test2stub;
var count = 0;

before(function () {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    //object is defined before
    test2stub = sinon.stub(object,"test2", function () {
        console.log("Count is: " + count);
        if (count === 0) {
            return (Bluebird.resolve(false));
        }
        else if (count === 1) {
            return (Bluebird.resolve(true));
        }
    });
    clock.tick(1000);    
    object.test("xyz")
    .then(function (data) {
        result = data;
    });
    clock.tick(1000);
    count = count + 1;
    clock.tick(1000);
});

after(function () {
    test2stub.restore();
    clock.restore();
});

it("result should be undefined. Check if test2 returned false first & true next", 
  function () {
    expect(result).to.be.undefined;
});
```

In the logs it shows that count has value 0 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code of `test` is actually incorrect. It never returns data on success. It returns `undefined`. The function should return data on success otherwise you won't be able to use it as parameter for next `.then` handler

   ```
   .then(function (data) {
       if (data) {
           return data;
       }
   ```
2. Next you make wrong assumptions about function `test`. It will NEVER return `undefined`. The function is rather dangerous and will call itself forever in an endless chain of promises until it squeezes out any not-null data from `test2`.
3. One shouldn't launch test code in `before` or `beforeEach` section. `before` and `after` are meant to prepare the environment like faking timers and then restoring them.
   One reason for calling tested code in the `it` handler is because promises should be handled differently. The handler should accept a parameter which indicates that the test will be asynchronous and the the test engine gives it a timeout (usually 10 secs) to complete. The test is expected to either call `done()` to indicate test is successful or call `done(error)` if it failed and there is an `error` object (or `expect` threw an exception).
   Also you should move the fake timer **after** the async operation started. In your code actually the first `clock.tick` is useless.
4. There is a trick with using `fakeTimers`. You can move time manually however it doesn't move on its own. For the first tick it works well. The promise is executed. However upon returning `.delay(1000)` promise, there will be no command to move the time forward. So, to finish the test correctly (not to modify tested code) you have also to stub `Bluebird.delay`

I would change the stubs implementation and do something like this

```
describe("test2", function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
        test2stub = sinon.stub(object,"test2", function () {
            console.log("Count is: " + count);
            return (Bluebird.resolve((count++) > 0));
        });
        var _delay = Bluebird.delay.bind(Bluebird);
        bluebirdDelayStub = sinon.stub(Bluebird,"delay", function (delay) {
            var promise = _delay(delay);
            clock.tick(1000);
            return promise;
        });
    })
    it("should eventually return true", function (done) {
        object.test("xyz")
        .then(function (data) {
            expect(data).to.be.true;
            expect(count).to.equal(2);
            done();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            done(err);
        });
        clock.tick(1000);
    });

    after(function () {
        test2stub.restore();
        clock.restore();        
        bluebirdDelayStub.restore();
    });    
})
```

*PS I verified this code under Node.js 0.10.35 and Bluebird 2.9.34*

Comment: @Kinil Thanks great points! Is there a reason you wrote clock.tick(2000) instead of 1000 ?

Comment: Check the updated answer. I expected it to trigger both promises (after each 1000 ms), however suspected a pitfall and I verified code in Node.js

Comment: Why are you stubbing Bluebird's delay function as well? Won't clock tick effect the delay function's time automatically?

Comment: Well perhaps I explained it not very clearly in 4. When using `fakeTimers` time should be moved manually every time to make timeouts trigger. Thus after calling `Bluebird.delay` there must code that executes `clock.tick`. Otherwise there is situation that you noticed: there is only one log in console with `count = 0` because `.delay` never resolves and `.then` never calls `test` again. There is another option. DO NOT use `fakeTimers`, however it's a bad approach because you will have a unit test that takes 2000 ms. There will always be warnings and tests will take too long